# Wordpress don't have plugin tab on dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I'm logged in as the administrator,
my site is self-hosted (the url is www.domain.com )

I'm not the one who built the site and I cant contact him,
this is the first time that I'm trying to install a plugin so I have never checked if it exists or not before today.

the problem is in the local version and in the online version.
thanks :-)

Comment: What shows up if you visit http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php ?

Comment: I have came across instances before where developers have purposely disabled plugins from the site owner to stop screwing up the site with junk. Do you have Access to Appearance >> Editor ? Do you have any access to the code?

Comment: @Dylan Hildenbrand's answer fixed it up, I had the remove_menu_page(..) function in the functions.php file, thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If an answer was did solve your problem, please mark it 'solved' for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Since your site is self-hosted, you can navigate to the folder wp-content -> plugins and add "zzzzz_" to the front of all plugins. This will disable all plugins without breaking anything. From there, see if your Plugins tab returns in the WordPress backend. If nothing happens, change the naming structure back.

After that, you'll want to download all of the files from your theme, which can be found in wp-content -> themes -> YOUR_THEME_NAME. From there, download the files, and KEEP A BACKUP. The file you'll be looking for in your theme is functions.php. Use CTRL + F (or whatever the search is in your favorite text editor) and find `remove_menu_page(` or `add_action('admin_menu'`. You'll want to look for something referencing plugins. [This site](http://seanbutze.com/removing-tabs-from-the-wordpress-admin-menu/) has some information on how to remove the plugins tab. There should be code using some of these functions specifically set to remove the plugins menu from your admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all plugins, and see if the tab return
You can do this only in this way: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/

Try to change theme,too.